# jQuery: Toggle is not working, help?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am using the toggle function from jQuery and for some reason is not working, this is what I have:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

            var flip = 1;
            $("#tg1").click(function () {
            $("#tg1-contenido").toggle( flip++ % 2 == 0 );
            });​
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Firebug is great for debugging this stuff, it tells you all the errors. http://getfirebug.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want every other click to toggle it's visibility, in which case you can just use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) without parameters, like this:

```
$("#tg1").click(function () {
  $("#tg1-contenido").toggle();
});
```

This will hide it if it's shown, and show it if it's hidden.

Also, I'm *assuming* your code got cut off, but make sure you're closing your `document.ready` wrapper correctly, that last line with only `}` should be a `});`.

Comment: Yes, I do have }); at the end, I'm sorry. It is still now working though

Comment: @fgualda87 - If this isn't working, you most likely have a JavaScript error, check your console!

Comment: Hey Nick, if I wanted to start with a hidden row. Like I want the first row of a table to be hidden, and when I click a button it should appear, so I'm using toggle. How do I make it hidden by default??